# Docker: How to prevent the use of latest image from docker registry?

Tags: docker

I was using centos image from https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/blalor/centos/

For some reason Blalor decided to remove passwd from the list of packages installed on the base image and my dockers stopped working on new deployments. Why does not docker know the build which was used for my dockers? I have had to change my base images now and change every server's docker image.

I could not use the tag feature because there is the tagging for the blalor's images? Do I have to use the source code and host the centos image myself so that it does not change again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use sources. If you have a working image, you can do `docker history <your image>` to see the image ID that was used and tag the proper one into `shortfellow/centos`. If you do not have a working image, on the link you provided, there is a `build detail` section with the history of build. You can see that on January 13th, 2014, it has been built and the image then was `a531daec9f98`. You can do `FROM a531daec9f98` on your dockerfile to make sure it will never change or you can `docker tag a531daec9f98 shortfellow/centos` (you will need to `docker pull a531daec9f98` before).

It is very similar to `git` in a sense that if you are using someone's repository, and if that someone does not use tags or branches, when he updates his reposiroty and you re pull, you will have the latest version with the new changes. In order to get back to the version you liked, you need to find the commit id. The solution would be to fork the repository. Which you can do on Docker by tagging the image under you username and pushing to a registry (`docker push username/image`)